# Google Analytics tracking code not installed

Tags: google-analytics

i am using google analytics to track my site. They said to add a tracking.js code to my site in every page to track the site. For which i made a google_analytics.js file, wrote the code there and included this file in everypage i need to track. But Google Analytics page is saying that track is not installed!

Comment: First off, google normally hosts the js file.. are you saying you downloaded it and are hosting it on your site?  2nd, did you include the rest of the on-page code, or did you just put a script include on your page? Who told you to do this? This *sounds* like really, *really* old instructions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google analytics provide this service through two js - ga.js and another is analytics.js

For ga.js, you need to write following code in each html page of your site -

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXX-X']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>
```

if you are using analytics.js, you need to write below code in each page of your site -

```
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-Y');
ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

please see this [link](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/) for more info -